# multiple recursion- 2 consecutive recursive calls one below the other

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int n){
    if(n>=0){
        printf("%d\n",n); 
        return fun(n-1);  //6 5 4  3  2  1  0
        return fun(n-3);   //4 3 2  1  0  -1  -2
    }
}
int main()
{ 
    printf ("%d", fun(7));
    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
-1
```

I don't understand where the -1 came from. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Second return will never be reached.

Comment: Your compiler probably complains about not returning a value for each path of your `fun` function. Not returning a value from a non-void function and using it in calling function invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: so the -1 was  printed because of undefined behaviour?

Comment: Yes. You should define what you expect to see for negative `n` to be returned.

Comment: oh u mean an else statement should be added

Comment: @Bhavna maybe an `else` should be added somewhere. The 2 problems in this your code have been discussed in the comments: Problem 1: when the program reaches the end of the function (if n < 0) then it returns nothing, and therefore the return value is garbage (-1 in your case, but it could as well be any other value). Problem 2: `return fun(n-3);`  is never reached.

Comment: I'm still a beginner so this might be a silly question. So whenever we use multiple recursive statements one below the other the second recursive statement never gets executed?

Comment: By definition code after `return` is never reached. It's totally unrelated to recursion. When the program flow reaches a `return` statement, the function is ended.

Comment: Look at this function: `void Test() {printf("1\n");  return; printf("2\n";}`. The second `printf` will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in OP's `fun()` definition:

1. The statement `return fun(n-3);` is never reached because it follows a previous `return` statement.
2. The function does not return a value when `n<0` leading to *undefined behavior*.

---

It is perfectly OK for a function to call itself recursively more than once. Here is an example of a function `fun()` calling itself either twice or no times, depending on the value of one of its parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void indent(int amount)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        putchar(' ');
    }
}

int fun(int level, int n)
{
    int ret;

    indent(level);
    printf("[fun level %d] n=%d\n", level, n);
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        int next_level;
        int a_n;
        int b_n;
        int a;
        int b;

        next_level = level + 1;
        a_n = n - 1;
        b_n = n - 3;
        indent(level);
        printf("[fun level %d][a] calling: fun(%d, %d)\n",
               level, next_level, a_n);
        a = fun(next_level, a_n);
        indent(level);
        printf("[fun level %d][a] fun(%d, %d) returned %d [=>a]\n",
               level, next_level, a_n, a);
        indent(level);
        printf("[fun level %d][b] calling: fun(%d, %d)\n",
               level, next_level, b_n);
        b = fun(next_level, b_n);
        indent(level);
        printf("[fun level %d][b] fun(%d, %d) returned %d [=>b]\n",
               level, next_level, b_n, b);
        ret = (a + b) / 2;
        indent(level);
        printf("[fun level %d] returning (a + b) / 2 [= %d]\n",
               level, ret);
        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = n;
        indent(level);
        printf("[fun level %d] returning %d\n", level, ret);
        return ret;
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    int init_level = 1;
    int init_n = 3;

    printf("[main] calling: fun(%d, %d)\n", init_level, init_n);
    printf("[main] fun(%d, %d) returned %d\n", init_level, init_n,
           fun(init_level, init_n));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[main] calling: fun(1, 3)
 [fun level 1] n=3
 [fun level 1][a] calling: fun(2, 2)
  [fun level 2] n=2
  [fun level 2][a] calling: fun(3, 1)
   [fun level 3] n=1
   [fun level 3][a] calling: fun(4, 0)
    [fun level 4] n=0
    [fun level 4][a] calling: fun(5, -1)
     [fun level 5] n=-1
     [fun level 5] returning -1
    [fun level 4][a] fun(5, -1) returned -1 [=>a]
    [fun level 4][b] calling: fun(5, -3)
     [fun level 5] n=-3
     [fun level 5] returning -3
    [fun level 4][b] fun(5, -3) returned -3 [=>b]
    [fun level 4] returning (a + b) / 2 [= -2]
   [fun level 3][a] fun(4, 0) returned -2 [=>a]
   [fun level 3][b] calling: fun(4, -2)
    [fun level 4] n=-2
    [fun level 4] returning -2
   [fun level 3][b] fun(4, -2) returned -2 [=>b]
   [fun level 3] returning (a + b) / 2 [= -2]
  [fun level 2][a] fun(3, 1) returned -2 [=>a]
  [fun level 2][b] calling: fun(3, -1)
   [fun level 3] n=-1
   [fun level 3] returning -1
  [fun level 2][b] fun(3, -1) returned -1 [=>b]
  [fun level 2] returning (a + b) / 2 [= -1]
 [fun level 1][a] fun(2, 2) returned -1 [=>a]
 [fun level 1][b] calling: fun(2, 0)
  [fun level 2] n=0
  [fun level 2][a] calling: fun(3, -1)
   [fun level 3] n=-1
   [fun level 3] returning -1
  [fun level 2][a] fun(3, -1) returned -1 [=>a]
  [fun level 2][b] calling: fun(3, -3)
   [fun level 3] n=-3
   [fun level 3] returning -3
  [fun level 2][b] fun(3, -3) returned -3 [=>b]
  [fun level 2] returning (a + b) / 2 [= -2]
 [fun level 1][b] fun(2, 0) returned -2 [=>b]
 [fun level 1] returning (a + b) / 2 [= -1]
[main] fun(1, 3) returned -1
```